# '(String) -> String' is not convertible to 'SQLHandler'

Tags: xcode, swift

The line below, at SQLHandler.translateQuery("Do mysql stuff"), is throwing the error: '(String) -> String' is not convertible to 'SQLHandler'. Why is it doing this? Thank you in advance.

*Code 1* (Used wherever and whenever needed)

```
var query: String = "mysql stuff"
SQLHandler.sendQuery(SQLHandler.translateQuery("domain and \(query)"))
```

*Code 2, SQLHandler.swift* (Called whenever needed)

```
import Foundation

class SQLHandler {

func translateQuery(queryToTranslate: String) -> String{
    println(queryToTranslate)
    return queryToTranslate.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "_", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
}

func sendQuery(query: String){
    println(query)
    let url = NSURL(string: "url and query goes here")

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in })
    task.resume()

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling an instance method on the class itself.

Either create an instance and call the method:

```
var sqlHandler = SQLHandler()
sqlHandler.translateQuery("domain and \(query)")
```

or define the methods as class methods :

```
class func translateQuery(queryToTranslate: String) -> String ...
class func sendQuery(query: String) ...
```